# Is there a parameter that is calculated as a range to mean ratio?

Tags: distributions, descriptive-statistics, dispersion

I was wondering whether it's me mis-remembering something or is there a dimensionless measure of dispersion calculated as: range/(mean or median). Where range is a difference between max and min values.

P.S. Could this be called "relative range"?

Comment: That wouldn't measure dispersion (no dimensionless value possibly could): it's a measure of *shape* for a non-negative variable.  The range itself is a (poor) measure of dispersion.

Comment: @whuber: range is a difference between max and min values.

Comment: I think everyone knows what the range is, but there are two possible areas in which it can be applied: to a *sample* or to a *distribution*.  In the latter case the range is not often used because the range is often infinite.  Thus I assumed you were asking about a sample.  Regardless, in either case the ratio of the range to a central statistic cannot measure dispersion.

Answer (score 3):

The measure can be seen in a few publications. I can remember a paper by Lord (1947) using the range as an approximation to the standard deviation for the t-test. So the range to mean ratio would be an approximation to the coefficient of variation which onestop has mentioned already.

Comment: With one df the range is not even an approximation--it's directly proportional to the SD :-).

Answer (score 2):

The [coefficient of variation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_variation) is defined as (standard deviation) / mean. Is that what you're thinking of??

Comment: That's a reasonable guess.  It still does not measure dispersion,though!